# Uniform-accelerated motion

Tags: calculus

> А car, which is initially at rest, moves time $t$ and travels $s_1$
>   (uniform-accelerated motion). The car is then traveling with
>   uniform-decelerated motion and stops for a time of $2t$, traveling the
>   distance of $s_2$. Determine the ratio of $s_1 / s_2$.

[image]

I want to apologize for my English. I really don't know most of the physical concepts and their names in English.

So, $s_1=\dfrac{at^2}{2}$. To calculate the second distance: $s_2=\dfrac{v_0^2}{2a}$, where $v_0$ is the beginning velocity (when the car starts to slow down). We know that $t_{stopping}=\dfrac{v_0}{a}, 2t=\dfrac{v_0}{a},v_0=2ta$. Therefore $s_2=\dfrac{4t^2a^2}{2a}=2at^2$. The ratio $s1/s2=1/4$ according to me. The answer given in my book is $1/2$. What's the problem with my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

- $ v_0-a_2\cdot 2t=0\implies at-a_2\cdot 2t=0\implies a_2=a/2$
- $s_2=v_0\cdot 2t-\frac12 a_2(2t)^2=2at^2-at^2=at^2$

Comment: Why is the first equality true?

Comment: The car must  stop after a time $2t$. There is a condition on the acceleration in the second part.

Comment: Is this the speed law? ($v_0-a_2 \cdot 2t$)

Comment: Yes exactly, the velocity is $0=v_0-a_2\cdot 2t$ and we kniw that $v_0=at$ therefore we can determine $a_2$.

Comment: Where $v_0$ is the speed when the car starts to slow down, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, I mean that!